# Python 2.7, comparing 3 columns of a CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

What is the easiest/simplest way to iterate through a large CSV file in Python 2.7, comparing 3 columns?

I am a total beginner and have only completed a few online courses, I have managed to use CSV reader to do some basic stats on the CSV file, but nothing comparing groups within each other.

The data is roughly set up as follows:

```
Group   sub-group   processed
1           a       y
1           a       y
1           a       y
1           b           
1           b
1           b
1           c       y
1           c       y
1           c
2           d       y
2           d       y
2           d       y
2           e       y
2           e
2           e
2           f       y
2           f       y
2           f       y
3           g
3           g
3           g
3           h       y
3           h
3           h
```

Everything belongs to a group, but within each group are sub-groups of 3 rows (replicates). As we are working through samples, we will adding to the processed column, but we don't always do the full complement, so sometimes there will only be 1 or 2 processed out of the potential 3.

I'm trying to work towards a statistic showing % completeness of each group, with a sub group being "complete" if it has at least 1 row processed (doesn't have to have all 3).

I've managed to get halfway there, by using the following:

```
for row in reader:
    all_groups[group] = all_groups.get(group,0)+1   
    if not processed == "":
        processed_groups[group] = processed_groups.get(group,0)+1

result = {}
for family in (processed_groups.viewkeys() | all_groups.keys()):
    if group in processed_groups: result.setdefault(group, []).append(processed_groups[group])
        if group in processed_groups: result.setdefault(group, []).append(all_groups[group])

for group,v1 in result.items():
        todo = float(v1[0])
        done = float(v1[1])
        progress = round((100 / done * todo),2)
        print group,"--", progress,"%"
```

The problem with the above code is it doesn't take into account the fact that some sub-groups may not be totally processed. As a result, the statistic will never read as 100% unless the processed column is always complete.

```
What I get:
Group 1 -- 55.56%
Group 2 -- 77.78%
Group 3 -- 16.67%

What I want:
Group 1 -- 66.67%%
Group 2 -- 100%
Group 3 -- 50%
```

How would you make it so that it just looks to see if the first row for each sub column is complete, and just use that, before continuing on to the next sub group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is with a couple of [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of sets. The first keeps track of all of the subgroups seen, the second keeps track of those subgroups that have been processed. Using a set simplifies the code somewhat, as does using a `defaultdict` when compared to using a standard dictionary (although it's still possible).

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

subgroups = defaultdict(set)
processed_subgroups = defaultdict(set)

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    for group, subgroup, processed in csv.reader(csvfile):
        subgroups[group].add(subgroup)
        if processed == 'y':
            processed_subgroups[group].add(subgroup)

    for group in sorted(processed_subgroups):
        print("Group {} -- {:.2f}%".format(group, (len(processed_subgroups[group]) / float(len(subgroups[group])) * 100)))
```

**Output**

```
Group 1 -- 66.67%
Group 2 -- 100.00%
Group 3 -- 50.00%
```